# Interference between amsmath and ntheorem

Tags: amsmath, theorems, ntheorem

I am having some problems that `seem' to me to be a conflict between amsmath and ntheorem. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm,right=2.00cm,top=2.45cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[amsmath,amstext,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{color,fancyhdr,framed,latexsym,multicols,slashed}

\theoremclass{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\newframedtheorem{Theorem}[Theorem]{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{Theorem}
Let $X$ be a set with $n$ elements. Then $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is a set with $2^n$ elements.
\end{Theorem}

\end{document}
```

Ay help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have to load the `amsmath` package; `ntheorem` doesn't do it and the options activates the compatibility mode. The option `amstext` doesn't exist. Check also `multicol` (not with a final `s`); the `\newframedtheorem` command is provided by `mdframed`.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks-How do I load the amsmath package wit ntheorem? Thanks again.

Comment: Just issue `\usepackage{amsmath}` before loading `ntheorem`.

Comment: @egreg: Just one more question on this, and please excuse my inexperience in this matter, but ?How do I convert the mdframed.dtx file into a .sty file? Thanks.

Comment: What system and TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: TeXlive on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @Michael: sadly the Ubuntu TeXLive is very very old (presumably 2009, not use if it has been updated for U12.04). Might be better to manually install the up to date TUG TeXLive. (TL 2011 has just been frozen).

Comment: @daleif: TL 2011 isn't fully frozen yet, just the executables. They still take package updates from CTAN.

Comment: @Martin: that is not how I read Karls message. TL11 is totally frozen, TL12 pretest will accept CTAN updates for another 2 weeks.

Comment: @daleif: Yes, you are right TL11 is totally frozen. CTAN package updates for the initial version of TL12 are still accepted. I confused these two.

Answer (score 3):

A minimal document that compiles is

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath} % necessary for the `amsmath` option
\usepackage{framed}  % necessary for the `\newframedtheorem` command
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,framed]{ntheorem}

\theoremclass{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\newframedtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{Theorem}
Let $X$ be a set with $n$ elements. Then $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is a set with $2^n$ elements.
\end{Theorem}

\end{document}
```

You're making some errors

1. In order to use the `amsmath` option in `ntheorem` you have to load `amsmath`
2. In order to use the `\newframedtheorem` command defined in `ntheorem` you have to load `framed` and pass the `framed` option.
3. You have a spurious `[Theorem]` in the definition of the environment.

However, the `mdframed` package is much more powerful for defining "boxed" theorems. Check [its documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mdframed/mdframed.pdf)

Comment: Or some picture examples: http://marcodaniel.github.com/mdframed/